# ios prepare for segue causing crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm brand new to ios development and have hit a brick wall with what I am trying to do.

I have this code in my method that is meant to pass on a specific NSObject from this view to the next view, however it keeps crashing my app.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPDF"]){
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    PDFViewController *controller = (PDFViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    controller.yourName = self.yourName;
}
```

I have debugged through and have identified that it is the fourth line causing it to crash.

Output:

```
2015-06-19 11:47:00.955 iOSPDFRenderer[2455:70005] -[PDFViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c5375d0
2015-06-19 11:47:00.959 iOSPDFRenderer[2455:70005] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c5375d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01f2b466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bb4a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01f332c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01e7bbc7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01e7b78e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   iOSPDFRenderer                      0x000ed00e -[ViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 238
    6   UIKit                               0x00985d77 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 199
    7   UIKit                               0x00985e05 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 116
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bca7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    9   UIKit                               0x00368340 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    10  UIKit                               0x003682d2 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    11  UIKit                               0x0049ca56 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    12  UIKit                               0x0049ce73 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    13  UIKit                               0x0049c0dd -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    14  UIKit                               0x003b8ffa -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    15  UIKit                               0x003b9ad5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    16  UIKit                               0x0037ebb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    17  UIKit                               0x0038ebf6 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21066
    18  UIKit                               0x00362bc7 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01e4e98f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01e4449d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01e439f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01e4337b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01e431ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x022da2c1 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x022da0fe GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x003669b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    27  iOSPDFRenderer                      0x000ec94d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02e58ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does any one have any ideas why this could be?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the crash message? it is impossible to say whats going on

Comment: Thanks Nick, I have added the message to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error log and code I think that you don't have navigation controller at the top. Try following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPDF"]){
        PDFViewController *controller = (PDFViewController *))segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.yourName = self.yourName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. It's strange though as I do have a navigation controller embeded in, so I don't know why this is the case?

Comment: well, I think you have that embedded before view controller calling show PDF, I think there is no new navigation controller after "showPDF" caller.

Comment: I think you could be correct there, in any case, it's working as needed now, so thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your segue is connected directly to a `PDFViewController`, not a `UINavigationController`. If that is really what you want, replace

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
PDFViewController *controller = (PDFViewController *)navController.topViewController;
```

with

```
PDFViewController *controller = (PDFViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

If you want the PDF view controller in a popup, insert a UINavigationController in the storyboard, make the PDF view controller its root view controller and change the segue type to modal. Your code should work correctly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

segues destination view controller is not navigation controller but its PDFViewController and you are explicitly typecasting it to UINavigation Controller